# how to solve this `The remote server returned an error: NotFound` in Silverlight + WCF`

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, webcam

hi I am new Silver light,
   I am doing one application which I would like to store images in server side using silver light plug-ins

I am using `WCF` services for sending images to server side

```
   public string EndSaveImageOnServer(System.IAsyncResult result) {
            object[] _args = new object[0];
            string _result = ((string)(base.EndInvoke("SaveImageOnServer", _args,     result)));//here i got error
            return _result;
        }
```

Comment: It could be any excpetion on the server when you get this error. Debug your program an turn on throw on .NET exceptions (menu Debug -> Exceptions)

Comment: Try to debug the service locally and find the exception, post the place where you ge the exception. Most probably your wcf service is not working.